# Switch button text value in Android Studio

Tags: java, button, android-studio

Hello stackoverflow community,

I decided to start learning how to make Android Apps in Android Studio and as a first project i thought it would be fun to make a simple calculation game.

First it generates a random sum, for example 5 + 5.Underneath the sum It has 4 buttons on which i want to generate the correct answer and three wrong answers. The player presses the button with the correct or wrong answer and the sum and the answers get generated again.

[image]

```
    // Generate wrong answers and convert
    int wronganswer1 = (answ1) + 2;
    String wronganswer1string = Integer.toString(wronganswer1);
    int wronganswer2 = (answ1) - 2;
    String wronganswer2string = Integer.toString(wronganswer2);
    int wronganswer3 = (answ1) + 3;
    String wronganswer3string = Integer.toString(wronganswer3);

    //Add Text to the buttons
    Button ansb1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.answerbutton1);
    ansb1.setText(answer);

    Button ansb2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.answerbutton2);
    ansb2.setText(wronganswer1string);

    Button ansb3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.answerbutton3);
    ansb3.setText(wronganswer2string);

    Button ansb4 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.answerbutton4);
    ansb4.setText(wronganswer3string);
```

This fills the text on the buttons with one correct answer and three wrong answers. The problem is that the correct answer will always be the button at the top.

My question is how to switch the values of the buttons each time a new sum is generated. So the correct answer wont always be on the same button.

Comment: Well, I guess it's not an android specific question :) one solution from the top of my head is to generate a random number from 0 to 3 and use a `switch` statement to choose where the correct answer goes, then distributing the rest answers to the buttons left

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an array to hold your answers.

```
String[] ans = new String[4];

int wronganswer1 = (answ1) + 2;
int wronganswer2 = (answ1) - 2;
int wronganswer3 = (answ1) + 3;

ans[0] = Integer.toString(answ1);
ans[1] = Integer.toString(wronganswer1);
ans[2] = Integer.toString(wronganswer2);
ans[3] = Integer.toString(wronganswer3);
```

Save your `Button` references to a `List`.

```
List<Button> btns = new ArrayList<Button>(4);

btns.add((Button)findViewById(R.id.answerbutton1));
btns.add((Button)findViewById(R.id.answerbutton2));
btns.add((Button)findViewById(R.id.answerbutton3));
btns.add((Button)findViewById(R.id.answerbutton4));
```

Now, use `Collections.shuffle()` to randomize the `Button`s

```
Collections.shuffle(btns);
```

and just iterate over the `List` to set the answers.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    btns.get(i).setText(ans[i]);
}
```

Comment: Hey, i was wondering if it is still possible to invoke onclick() on a specific button after this code has switched them around.

Comment: Your button handler for all the four buttons could be the same. It can distinguish between the actual buttons by using a `switch (view.getId())`.

Answer (score 0):

You should set up a randomized on the buttons so the strings would intercept the calculations so it would be like if (right answer) is # go to button #, wrong answer is #-# go to button #